# Foundation sass - setting rows to be expanded by default

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am using [Foundation for sites 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html) and I am wondering, how can I set the rows to be `expanded` by default in sass `_settings` file, so that I don't have to add `expanded` class to each row in the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings file you'll find a section for Grid around line 91. You can set the $grid-row-width to `100%` in place of `$global-width`.

```
// 3. The Grid
// -----------

$grid-row-width: $global-width;  // change to 100%
...
```

**Or** you can change the value of the `$global-width` variable to `100%`.

```
$global-width: rem-calc(1200); // change to 100%
```

**Please note** that this is going to globally effect your your grid though.  If you're unsure that you want this done globally, you might want to create a mixin for a full width row.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html